# PHP+mysql: how to store big integers

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database for an online game, and i need to store total score of user playing game. Each time user end a match, his score will be automatically updated.
I'm trying to keep this score as VARCHAR, then retrieve it from a script, parse to int, add last score, parse again to string, and update database. But as i can see, php is not able to manage big numbers. How can i do?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html - `INT`? - `BIGINT`?

Comment: How big numbers you have? Storing integers as strings is bad idea. Forget.

Comment: An unsigned bigint will go up to 18446744073709551615. That should be big enough for a score in a game. I agree with panther, converting back and forwards to a string is a bad idea.

Comment: i've think the same, but what happen if, hypothetically, user reach maximum of score that bigint could store?

Comment: @giozh: We can divide the number by another number (e.g 2) and store in the db. Multiply it by 2 again when you fetch it for the display... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has `BIGINT` type. PHP itself works flawlessly with `BIGINT`.

Unless you want numbers way bigger than that, I have no idea why would you use anything else.

*Note: unsigned BIGINT is twice as big as BIGINT*

`unsigned BIGINT` can store numbers up to: **18,446,744,073,709,551,615**
`signed BIGINT` can store numbers up to: **9,223,372,036,854,775,807** *(or with `8` at the end on the negative side)*

So basically, You can store numbers up to around 1,8*10^19. Need more? Then look at [`BC` at the other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28767009/3720605).

For comparison:
`INT` can store up to *2,147,483,647* or twice as much when `unsigned`, which means that `BIGINT` is roughly *4,294,967,295*  **times** larger than `INT`. Yes. `BIGINT` is basically very close to `INT^2`

Comment: Your second sentence negates the first one. MySQL `BIGINT` does not work flawlessly with PHP. Also "unsigned BIGINT" is twice as big as `BIGINT` is false. They have the same size, just different value range. This answer will confuse beginners a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[You need to use BC](http://php.net/bc):

You can work with numbers as strings in PHP using BC, so they are arbitrary big, as you are already using in your database.

Best regards.